# Populate model with metadata of file uploaded through django admin

Tags: django, file-upload, django-models, django-admin

I have two models,`Foto` and `FotoMetadata`. `Foto` just has one property called upload, that is an upload field. `FotoMetadata` has a few properties and should receive metadata from the foto uploaded at `Foto`. This can be done manually at the admin interface, but I want to do it automatically, i.e: when a photo is uploaded through admin interface, the `FotoMetadata` is automatically filled.

In my **model.py** I have a few classes, including Foto and FotoMetadata:

```
class Foto(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to="fotos")

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' %(self.upload)

class FotoMetadata(models.Model):
    image_formats = (
        ('RAW', 'RAW'),
        ('JPG', 'JPG'),
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    camera = models.ForeignKey(Camera, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    format =  models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=image_formats)
    exposure = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    fnumber = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    iso = models.IntegerField()
    foto = models.OneToOneField(
        Foto,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
```

When I login at the admin site, I have an upload form related to the `Foto`, and this is working fine. My problem is that I can't insert metadata at `FotoMetadata` on the go. I made a function that parse the photo and give me a dictionary with the info I need. This function is called GetExif is at a file called **getexif.py**. This will be a simplified version of it:

```
def GetExif(foto):
    # Open image file for reading (binary mode)
    f = open(foto, 'rb')

    # Parse file
    ...
    <parsing code>
    ...
    f.close()

    #create dictionary to receive data
    meta={}
    meta['date'] = str(tags['EXIF DateTimeOriginal'].values)
    meta['fnumber'] = str(tags['EXIF FNumber'])
    meta['exposure'] = str(tags['EXIF ExposureTime'])
    meta['iso'] = str(tags['EXIF ISOSpeedRatings'])
    meta['camera'] =str( tags['Image Model'].values)

    return meta
```

So, basically, what I'm trying to do is use this function at admin.py to automatically populate the `FotoMetadata` when uploading a photo at `Foto`, but I really couldn't figure out how to make it. Does any one have a clue?

---

**Edit 24/03/2016**

Ok, after a lot more failures, I'm trying to use *save_model* in **admin.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Autor, Camera, Lente, Foto, FotoMetadata
from fotomanager.local.getexif import GetExif

admin.site.register(Autor)
admin.site.register(Camera)
admin.site.register(Lente)
admin.site.register(FotoMetadata)

class FotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # populate the model
        obj.save()
        # get metadata
        metadados = GetExif(obj.upload.url)
        # Create instance of FotoMetadata
        fotometa = FotoMetadata()
        # FotoMetadata.id = Foto.id
        fotometa.foto = obj.pk
        # save exposure
        fotometa.exposure = metadados['exposure']

admin.site.register(Foto, FotoAdmin)
```

I thought it would work, or that I will have problems saving data to the model, but actually I got stucked before this. I got this error:

> Exception Type:   FileNotFoundError
>   Exception Value:
>   [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/fotos/IMG_8628.CR2'
>   Exception Location: /home/ricardo/Desenvolvimento/fotosite/fotomanager/local/getexif.py in GetExif, line 24

My GetExif function can't read the file, however, the file path is right! If I copy and paste it to my browser, it downloads the file. I'm trying to figure out a way to correct the address, or to pass the internal path, or to pass the real file to the function instead of its path. I'm also thinking about a diferent way to access the file at GetExif() function too. Any idea of how to solve it?

---

**Solution**

I solved the problem above! By reading the FileField source, I've found a property called `path`, which solve the problem. I also made a few other modifications and the code is working. The class FotoAdmin, at **admin.py** is like this now:

```
class FotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # populate the model
        obj.save()
        # get metadata
        metadados = GetExif(obj.upload.path)
        # Create instance of FotoMetadata
        fotometa = FotoMetadata()
        # FotoMetadata.id = Foto.id
        fotometa.foto = obj
        # set and save exposure
        fotometa.exposure = metadados['exposure']
        fotometa.save()
```

I also had to set `null=True` at some properties in **models.py** and everything is working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to enable post_save a signal
read : [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/signals/)

Activate the post_save signal - so after you save a FOTO you have a hook to do other stuff, in your case parse photometa and create a FotoMetadata instance.

More, if you want to save the foto only if fotometa succeed , or any other condition you may use , pre_save signal and save the foto only after meta foto was saved.

Comment: I made a research and end using `save_model`. But I'm having problems to access the uploaded file. I can only access it instace. I edited the original post with more info.

Comment: The line 24 is `f = open(foto, 'rb')`. Thanks for your help, it helped me a lot when I just stucked. I already solve the problem and post the solution! Thanks!